# Python Requests: Accepting a TOS before accessing a page

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests

I am a newbie trying to write a python script to scrape some information from a website. I need to get to the search page of the website, but on a new session it will redirect you to a TOS acceptance page. You click yes or no to accept, and then it will move you to the search page. Here is my code:

```
import requests

s=requests.Session()
page = s.get("http://probate.cuyahogacounty.us/pa/CaseSearch.aspx")
if ('TOS.aspx' in page.url):
    print("Attempt to agree to TOS")
    yesBtn={'ctl00$mpContentPH$btnYes': 'Yes'}
    r=s.post(page.url, data=yesBtn)
    r2=s.get("http://probate.cuyahogacounty.us/pa/CaseSearch.aspx")
    print (r.url)
    print (r2.url)
```

Both r and r2 kick me back to the TOS URL. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of website need a cookiejar or some "object" to store the session.

Try this.

```
import requests
import lxml.html


base_url = 'http://probate.cuyahogacounty.us'
with requests.Session() as s:

    url = base_url + '/pa/CaseSearch.aspx'
    resp = s.get(url,allow_redirects=False)
    url_tos = base_url + resp.headers['Location']

    resp = s.get(url_tos)
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)

    vgenerator = root.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]//@value')[0]
    viewstate = root.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]//@value')[0]

    eventvalidation = root.xpath('//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]//@value')[0]

    data = {
      'ajax_HiddenField': '',
      '__EVENTTARGET': '',
      '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
      '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vgenerator,
      '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
      'ctl00$mpContentPH$btnYes': 'Yes'
    }

    r = s.post(url_tos,data=data)

    print r.text
```